# Questions about tor, tor browser and the possibility of 6 relays stacking

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, torsocks

If I run tor through socks proxy (127.0.0.1:9050) installed from `sudo apt install tor` on linux mint 18 and I browse with the tor browser bundle, does that mean I going through 6 relays? If so how could I configure back to 3 relays on my tor browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Tor Browser will launch it's own `tor` process by default and both will connect to the Tor network separately.

So unless you've knowingly configured your system daemon instance of `tor` to act as a transparent proxy and set some `iptables` rules to enforce it, you will not be creating a "Tor-over-Tor" situation (I.E. you won't be connecting through "6 relays"). They are intended to play nice together.